# Contiguous records in SQL queries involving joins

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, left-join

I know that (without the `order by` clause) SQL does not make any guarantees about the order of the result set. However, with respect to queries that involve one or more joins can I make any assumptions about the *contiguousness* of related items in the result set?

For example, if I have a query like

```
select * from A left join B on P(x) left join C on Q(x)
```

can I assume that all of the records corresponding to a particular row in **`A`** will be contiguous in the result set?

Comment: No I don't think you can. It depends on the optimiser and what indexes it uses to join and create the result sets. Why would you want to assume anyway - doesn't that create needless risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot.  The result of the query is never specified unless there is an `order by` clause.

Here is a real example with the results are not contiguous.  A parallel hash join separates the table on different processors based on the join key.  The results are then compiled as they become available.  So some of the results come from one processor, some come from another, and so on.

Or, in another case, you might be using an index lookup.  However, SQL Server may decide to use an index on A rather than B -- and go through the rows sequentially in B rather than A.  The same id may appear more than one time in table B.  So, a given row A might appear in the results wherever B.id = A.id.